# Unique view counter mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For example I have two pages: `page.php?id=1` and `page.php?id=2`. When user hits `page.php?id=1`, it will count as 1 view and *mysql* will save the IP address to count the unique visitors. But if the same user hits `page.php?id=2`, it doesn't count as unique visitor.

Here is MySQLi code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["keywordid"]);
$encode = ip2long($ip);
$viewcheck = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM ip_address WHERE ip = $encode");
$viewrow = mysqli_num_rows($viewcheck);
if($viewrow == 0) { mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE keywords SET keyword_count = keyword_count + 1 where keyword_id = $id");
}
```

Comment: Do you use tracking tools like google analytics?

Comment: What's the question? What did you try? Did you debug `$viewrow` to check if the query is executed for `id=2`? Since the ip address is in the table as soon as the user hits `id=1`, the viewcheck/viewresult will be 1 and thus your counter query is not executed for `id=2`.

Comment: Yes i know that. So is it possible to turn $viewrow = 0 when user hits (with the same ip) id=2 and etc.?

Comment: Do a second check and see if the user already visited id=2 or not. But why not remove that check altogether?